# copy contents from one excel workbook to another in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to copy contents of one excel workbook to another excel workbook.
POI API does not have a method for it. Is there any method to do the same?

Comment: open the workbook and save it as a new workbook

Answer (score 1):

Is there one specific method? Not that I'm aware of

Though, are you wanting to add the information of that workbook into an already existing workbook? Or do you just want a copy of that workbook as @Luiggi is suggesting?

To copy the contents of a workbook to an already existing workbook I would iterate through the workbook, going through the sheets, then a loop for the rows to place the cell values into a map or list (depending on what you have and what you're getting) and then iterate through that map or list and write those cells into the existing workbook.